# can any equation have an unlimited number of solutions

Tags: polynomials

If I am trying to find the value of $x$ when $x^2 + 4x + 4 = 0$ and I realize that if $x^2 + 4x + 4 = 0$ then $(x+2)(x+2)=0$, and then I decide to multiply both sides by $(x-54)(x+3)(x-12)(x-4)(x+27)$ to get $(x+2)(x+2)(x-54)(x+3)(x-12)(x-4)(x+27)=0$, and then divided by $(x+2)^2$ to get $(x-54)(x+3)(x-12)(x-4)(x+27)=0$ and then I realized that if a product is equal to zero, then one or more of it's multiplicands must be equal to zero, which means that $(x-54)=0∨(x+3)=0∨(x-12)=0∨(x-4)=0∨(x+27)=0$ which means that $x=54∨-3∨12∨4∨-27$.  Is there anything wrong with this logic?

Comment: Yes, what's wrong is you've brought in extraneous solutions$\,-\,$that is, solutions to the new equation that are not solutions of the original equation.

Comment: I asked if there was anything illogical about the method I used to solve the equation.

Comment: Yes, it makes no sense to multiply by _arbitrary_ factors if you are trying to solve the original equation.

Comment: Sometimes you _have_ to multiply by algebraic factors (e.g., clearing denominators), but then you need to check to make sure the solutions at the end are not extraneous.

Comment: Your goal is to solve $x^2 + 4x + 4 = 0$. No matter which method you use, make sure your answers are correct by subbing the value into your original equation. You'll find that only $x = -2$ works.

Comment: If you multiply an equation with an expression that can be $0$, the multiplication is only then an equivalence transformation, if the expression is not $0$. If we insert the value for which the expression is $0$, the new equation becomes $0=0$, which is always true, but the original equation need not hold for the inserted value. So, in general you get new solutions.

Comment: If I am using a completely logical approach and maintain equality, then why should I have to check the answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You proved the following thing:

If $x$ is a solution to $x^2+4x+4=0$ then $x=-2∨54∨-3∨12∨4∨-27$.

Which means, that you found the **possible** solutions, not necessarily the solutions. You still have to check if these numbers are solutions.

**Note:** When we solve an equation, if every step is "if and only if", then what we get at the end are exactly the solutions. But if any step is **NOT** reversible, like for example squaring both sides, or multiplying by a quantity which could be zero, then not all the numbers you get are necessary solutions, they are only potential solutions. You have to check among them which are solutions.

And in this sense, you are right: any equation has an infinite number of **potential solutions**. But we already knew that: any number could be a solution.

Comment: What if you divided the equation by $(x+2)$ so that -2 was no longer a solution.  Then none of them are potential solutions.

Comment: @Vityou You can never divide by 0! If you want to divide an equation by $x+2$ you must first make sure that $x+2$ cannot be $0$.

Answer (score 1):

To demonstrate the error more drastically : The equation $$1=2$$ has obviously no solution. But if we multiply with $x-1$, we get $$x-1=2(x-1)$$ Now , $1$ is a solution, so the set of solutions has changed. Therefore the multiplication with $x-1$ is not an equivalence transformation.

Answer (score 0):

Your initial step is correct. 
Factoring the polynomial $p(x)=x^2+4x+4$ as $(x+2)^2$ gives you the root $x=-2$ with multiplicity 2.
The following steps however are incorrect.
Multiplying the polynomial by, say, $(x+3)$ gives a *new* polynomial with roots $-2$ and $-3$.
However, $-3$ is *not* a root of your original polynomial, since $p(-3) = (-3)^2+4\cdot(-3)+4 = 1 \neq 0$